# Assigning value that contains special characters to variable looses special characters

Tags: t-sql, collation

So this is weird issue that is related to only one letter: **ț** I'm talking about Microsoft SQL Server and database that has Collation property set to Romanian_CI_AS.

When I launch this query:

```
select name from mytable where id = 1
```

I'm getting correct result containing this special character. But when I'm launching this query:

```
declare @name varchar(max) = (select name from mytable where id = 1)
select @name
```

or this one:

```
declare @name varchar(max) = (select name COLLATE Romanian_CI_AS from mytable where id = 1)
select @name
```

I'm seeing **?** instead of this particular letter. Any other special characters work fine.

Do you know how can I assign this value to a variable without loosing mentioned letter?

Comment: use nvarchar(max) instead of varchar(max)

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple... Thanks a lot!